# Find all integers $x$ and $y$ such that $4y^2=x^7+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all integers $x$ and $y$ such that $4y^2=x^7+1$.

I first subtract one from both sides to get $4y^2-1=x^7$, which can be factored into $(2y+1)(2y-1)=x^7$. From here, I can not proceed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(2y+1,2y-1)=1$.

Comment: $2y-1$ and $2y+1$ must both be odd $7$ th powers, and the only possibility is $y=0$ and therefore $x=-1$

Answer (score 2):

You have $(2y+1)(2y-1)=x^7$. Then $2y+1$ and $2y-1$ have no common
prime factor (why?) so each prime factor of $2y+1$ must occur seven, or
fourteen, or .... times. Similarly for $2y-1$.

Comment: Could you please expand on your explanation of "why"? I do not understand why (2y-1) and (2y+1) cannot have the same prime factor. Why cant it happen that one of the factors of (2y-1) is p^(7k-m) and one the the factors of (2y+1) is p^m, which when multiplied comes to p^(7k)? I hope my wording is clear.

Comment: $2y+1$ and $2y-1$ aren't very far apart.... @LeastSquaresWonderer

Comment: Yes, I understand it intuitively, but I do not know how to derive it or prove it. Could you assist me by expanding a bit?

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer 
Thenks to Euclid algorithm
$$\text{GCD}(2y+1,2y-1)=\text{GCD}(2y-1,(2y+1)-(2y-1))=\text{GCD}(2y-1,2)=1$$
So $2y+1$ and $2y-1$ are coprime. BTW I got the solution $x=-1;\;y=0$ and nothing else

Comment: $2y+1=p^7$ and $2y-1=q^7$ implies $2=p^7-q^7$ which is impossible (why?).

Comment: @Piquito $2=p^7-q^7$ is possible: $(p,q)=(1,-1)$. But the function $x\mapsto x^7$ grows quickly; unless $|x"$ is very small $(x+1)^7$ is a lot bigger than $x^7$.

Comment: $p$ and $q$  are obviously supposed to be prime numbers, not $1$, in your reasoning. Cordial greetings .

Comment: @Piquito $p,q$ don't have to be prime. If $ab=x^{k}$, $k\ge 1$, $a,b,x,k\in\mathbb Z$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $|a|=c^k$, $|b|=d^k$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb Z$, where I used absolute value signs, which are important when $k$ is even. $c,d$ don't have to be prime.

Comment: I think I should say here that if we had $ab=x^{2k}$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ for some $k\ge 1$, $a,b,x,k\in\mathbb Z$, then generally you would have to say that $|a|=c^{2k}$, $|b|=d^{2k}$ for some $c,d\in\mathbb Z$, where I used absolute value signs. Notice that, e.g., when $a=-4$, $b=-9$, $x=6$, $k=1$, then $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $k\ge 1$, $a,b,x,k\in\mathbb Z$, $(-4)\cdot (-9)=6^{2\cdot 1}$, but $-4<0\le \left(c^1\right)^2$, so $-4\neq c^{2\cdot 1}$.

Comment: My comment goes about the first answer to this problem!

Answer (score 2):

$4y^2=x^7+1$ is clearly a case of the equation $y^2=x^p+1$ where $p$ is odd prime and has always the trivial solution $x=-1$.

$► p=3$: Euler proved that the only solutions are $x=0,-1,2$.

$►p\gt3$: Nagell proved that in order there is solution it is necessary that
$$p\equiv1\pmod8\text{ and }y\equiv0\pmod p$$ 
Thus $4y^2=x^7+1$ has only the trivial solution $x=-1$ since 
$7$ is not congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

(T. Nagell. *Sur l'impossibilité de l'équation indéterminée $z^p+1=y^2$. Norsk Mat. Forenings Skrifter, **1** (1921),Nr. 4*)